# How can i see my website layout in mobile phone?

Tags: autolayout, vs-web-site-project

I've developed a website in my pc and the layout is good in laptop 
But i want to see its mobile phone accessing  layout ,before hosting. 
Please help me in this. Thanks.

Comment: Most modern browsers have the capability to change your viewport or set to "mobile mode." You'll have to do some searching to get specifics for your browser though.

Comment: does compatibility mode really cover JavaScript compatibility ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer tootks that are already built in web browsers.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode

Also if you realy want it to test on actual mobile create wireless connection using hotspot betwen mobile and laptop. Now your PC and mobile will get private IP addresses for this wireless connection.

Check you PC ip address for this connection and configure your webserver to listen on that IP address.

Now you can access your website on mobile with that IP as url and you can check your website layout.

Comment: this does not really work 100%. simply because part of testing on real devices is checking JavaScript which the desktop browser does not do.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Google Chrome,

- Open `Developer Tools`
- Select `Toggle Device Toolbar`
  [image]
- Select the device you like to simulate from the toolbar.
  [image]

Comment: this does not really work 100%. simply because part of testing on real devices is checking JavaScript which the desktop browser does not do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a webserver locally or just editing HTML files and viewing them in your browser?

If you are just opening HTML files in your browser then run a local web server on your computer like http-server.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

If you are running a web server locally then your phone should be able to hit the same test url if you are on the same network.

Comment: that is true only if your dev server is bound to your local LAN. i work in visual studio which bind to localhost.